Unable to use images with jsPDF
everyone,
I'm trying to create a pdf file with jsPDF but I need a logo at the top of the page.
I've tried a .jpg and a .png file bu I always get the erro that the file is not a .jpg file or a .png file.
I've tried everything I can remember and I cant't make it work and it's a pity because jsPDF is very straight forward to use.
Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance
I tried several different images and expected the image to appear in the created pdf.

Show us what you are doing don’t tell us because we believe you but we need to see code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
